# how to receive data from real time database in firebase in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I want to receive data from the realtime database in firebase. The Data is shown below:
[image]

The code I tried is

```
return this.db.list('messages', ref => {
  return ref.limitToLast(25).orderByKey();
});
```

but it's not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this to get the messages list from the firestore. Import **AngularFireDatabase** service and **AngularFireList** to store message collection.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from '@angular/fire/database';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MessageService {
  
    messages: AngularFireList<any>;
  
   constructor(private http: HttpClient, private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

   /**
     * Get All tickers from firebase
     */
    getMessages(): Observable<any> {
      this.messages = this.db.list('messages');
      return this.messages.valueChanges();
    }

}
```

Make sure you have imported **AngularFireModule** and **AngularFireDatabaseModule** in your app module.

Answer (score 2):

AngularFire is build with the Observable Pattern via RxJs Library.

You can stream the data with the valueChanges() method, as described [in the documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md)

```
items: Observable<any[]>;
constructor(firestore: AngularFirestore) {
   this.items = firestore.collection('items').valueChanges();
}
```

Comment: I am using realtime database not cloud firestore

Comment: It's the exact same principle. Look at the documentation :
https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md#dynamic-querying